# Problem installing npm in laravel framework "Pip install npm"

Tags: npm, pip

I am writing this code

```
pip install npm
```

But in the terminal it returns:

> Requirement already satisfied: npm in c:\programm files\python36\lib\site-packages

How can I solve it?

Comment: `npm` is already installed ? What happen if you type `python -c 'import npm' ?

Comment: Npm is already installed so why are you trying to install it again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install npm in laravel 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249800/how-can-i-install-npm-in-laravel-5-4)